# ERROR Invalid options in vue.config.js: "baseUrl" is not allowed

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

```
user@host:/var/www/abc/def/frontend# npm run serve

> frontend@0.1.0 serve /var/www/abc/def/frontend
> vue-cli-service serve

 ERROR  Invalid options in vue.config.js: "baseUrl" is not allowed
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! frontend@0.1.0 serve: `vue-cli-service serve`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the frontend@0.1.0 serve script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-05-23T20_18_30_614Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a coding issue, the problem is that vue ui still adds baseUrl to the vue config file on save, but it has been deprecated and replaced by publicPath.

So because it is deprecated, vue cli will create an error by its own generated file ^^.

This can easily be fixed by changing vue ui to update vue config file by `publicPath` instead of `baseUrl`.

[Source](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/5162)